# Match Json keys and replace with values in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

So given a simple json object

```
[
  {"a": 1},
  {"b": 2},
  {"c": 3},
  {"d": 4}
]
```

and an array like this

```
var arr = ["A", "B", "C"];
```

I want to write the most efficient function to match the lower case keys with their upper case counter parts and replace them with the uppercase letters, I started by turning the array into a object so I wont have to iterate over and over again, but Im stuck. Can someone please show me how they would handle this in the most efficient way?

Comment: Are you expecting for all keys to be changed _except_ `d`?

Answer (score 0):

Without further information on your amount of keys/possible keys, trying to make a generic solution would be like this:

```js
var arr = [
  {"a": 1},
  {"b": 2},
  {"c": 3},
  {"d": 4}
]

var match = ["A", "B", "C"];

var objMatch = {}

for(var i=0;i<match.length;i++) objMatch[match[i].toLowerCase()] = match[i] // pass it to an object for efficient matching

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    for(var key in arr[i]){ // check if we need to replace the key
        if(objMatch.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            var temp = arr[i][key] // keep old value
            delete arr[i][key] // delete key
            arr[i][objMatch[key]] = temp // set new key with same old value
        }
    }
}

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a=[
 {"a": 1},
 {"b": 2},
 {"c": 3},
 {"d": 4}
];

var arr = ["A", "B", "C"];
```

Define a method in Object's prototype chain to rename Object keys:

```
Object.prototype.changeKey = function (oName, nName) {
   if (oName == nName) {
       return this;
   }
   if (this.hasOwnProperty(oName)) {
      this[nName] = this[oName];
      delete this[oName];
   }
 return this; 
};
```

Then find the key which matches the elements of array, then change it:

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   for(key in a[i]){
   if(key === arr[i].toLowerCase()){a[i].changeKey (key,arr[i])}
  }
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u409y2uq/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an helper object and loop throu all items and all keys.

```js
var arr0 = [{ "a": 1 }, { "b": 2 }, { "c": 3 }, { "d": 4 }],
    arr1 = ["A", "B", "C"],
    obj = Object.create(null);

arr1.forEach(function (a) {
    obj[a.toUpperCase()] = a;
});
arr0.forEach(function (a) {
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        var v = a[k];
        if (k.toUpperCase() in obj) {
            delete a[k];
            a[obj[k.toUpperCase()]] = v;
        }
    });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr0, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand from your question

```
var arrayOne = [
{"a": 1},
{"b": 2},
{"c": 3},
{"d": 4}
];
var arrayTwo = ["A", "B", "C"];
var tempArray = {};
$.each(arrayOne, function(key,value){
  for(arrayOneKey in value){
    $.each(arrayTwo, function(index,vl) {
      if(vl.toLowerCase() == arrayOneKey.toLowerCase()){
        tempArray[vl]=key+1;
      }
    });
  }
});
console.log(tempArray);
```

Comment: You might want to consider rewriting the jQuery to vanilla JS as it isn't mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make things complicated. Use `map` and return a new array:

```
function transform(arr, keys) {
  return arr.map(function(el) {
    var obj = {};
    var key = Object.keys(el)[0];
    var uc = key.toUpperCase();
    obj[keys.indexOf(uc) > -1 ? uc : key] = el[key];
    return obj;
  });
}

transform(input, arr);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/o8qnc2sg/1/)